# IOS7 - performSegueWIthIdentifier does not have any effect

Tags: ios, storyboard, ios7, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a problem in iOS7 where I am calling a segue with `performSegueWithIdentifier` (I have code just like this that works just about everywhere else), then I log the segue in `prepareForSegue`, then I log again the view controller (VC) that the segue is supposed to push to the top.

`prepareForSegue` gets called appropriately and the segue has the correct string as its identifier property. Yet the VC that it is supposed to push to the top never gets initialized nor `viewWillAppear` gets called.

The segue I am talking about, which is the only one that does not work (all the other ones work in both ios6 and 7), is the one leading form the center VC to the right VC. By the way, this works flawlessly in iOS6.

What could be the cause?

the code:

```
-(IBAction)gotoMainMenu:(id)sender{

    DLog(@"DifferentName");

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DifferentName" sender:self];


}
```

[image]

Comment: Image is low quality but it looks like you have seague from right VC to center VC, not center -> right. Or you have 2 ? If so - make sure you are calling right one.

Comment: I have a similar issue at present, what happens when the segue is triggered in the application nothing? What happens if you tap anywhere on the screen again once waiting for the segue to occur, does this make the segue happen?

Comment: I have verified that I am calling the right one as this is working perfectly in ios6. @StuartM -- nothing happens when I tap the screen again.

Comment: Are they triggered from a button or from a cell? Can you provide the prepareForSegue method in your question. I would triple check you have the right segue, as you see they join. You need to click on the segue path not the segue circle and check the segueName you have provided, make sure they are not the same for both directions in/out.

Comment: I have checked that, thanks for the suggestion! The segue is triggered from within a button

Comment: Are you calling super prepareForSegue in that method?

Comment: no, prepareForSegue gets called as a delegate. Should I be calling super?

Comment: @stackOverFlew: Can you share a source code of this project or maybe a simplified version of it that has the same problem?

Comment: i worked around the problem for now by not using that seugue. There is no more relevant source code than that which i posted...

Comment: @stackOverFlew have you found any solution? I got the same problem...

Comment: @GustavoBarbosa nope sorry -- i had to redesign my storyboard a little bit... hope its not a lot of changes for you. I would delete the prior segues to identify which one is a problem then redesign around that one...

Comment: @stackOverFlew No, my storyboard is ok. It's just one segue where the problem is happening... I've already ask at Apple Developer Forum, but nobody knows a solution

Comment: right-- the solution i implemented was to redesign the storyboard so that you do not need that segue

Comment: Segue's are painful. Manual Push/Pop is a staple of MVC and should be adopted at ALL times. Could be your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Get in the habit of not wiring up segue's to buttons.  Wire them up to the VC and then in the touchUpInside action, fire off the performSegueWithIdentifier.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it as follows.  In view A I had a segue that was triggered by a button (UIButton) and the button was also connected to an action in my controller.  When I clicked the button in View A, View B would appear as expected.  However, when I tried clicking a button in View B to go to View C nothing happened just as you described above.

In my case the issue was resolved in View A.  I removed the segue that was tied to the button  and let the IBAction that was associated with the button handle calling the performSegueWithIdentifier, then I created a new manual segue that was only tied to the view and voila things worked as expected again.

In short, I guess make sure you don't have both and action and a segue linked to the same button.  Hope this helps.